# PHP условие при выборке

Tags: php, mysqli

Этот вопрос уже был (с моей стороны) , сейчас сформулировал его немного по другому. Так как первый не дал ожидаемых результатов. Видимо не правильно тогда сформулировал за что прошу прощения дорогие друзья. Вообщем вывожу всех пациентов из таблицы patients таким банальным образом :

```
<tbody> <?php  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM patients ") 
            or die(mysqli_error());         
             ?> 
       <?php    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) { ?>                                 <tr>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["card_id"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["fio"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["adress"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["phone"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>">Посмотреть</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="del_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>">Удалить</a> <a href="edit_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>" rel = "facebox">Изменить  </a></td>

                                        </tr><?php }; ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Среди выводимых пациентов есть и такие у кого нету ни одного приёма в таблице priem. На mysql определяю их таким образом

```
SELECT * FROM patients WHERE card_id NOT IN (SELECT card_id FROM priem)
```

mysql выводит мне их нормально. Однако как обьяснить PHP чтоб он при выводе красил их в красный шрифт. Тут собственно получаеться два вопроса : 
1. В моём случаи надо объединить 2 запроса в один ? Если да то как подскажите подалуйста. 
2. И потом как сказать PHP (как поставить условие, глядя на что) чтоб он покрасил их в красный цвет.

Был бы благодарен за помощь дорогие друзья

Comment: Если коротко, то результат запроса `SELECT card_id FROM patients WHERE card_id NOT IN (SELECT card_id FROM priem)` поместить в массив `$aNoPriem`. У вас будет массив ид пользователей без приема. А уже при выводе пациентов проверять `in_array($row['card_id'], $aNoPriem)` и красить строку красным.

Comment: Ivan Bolnikh, спасибо Вам ответ. Хорошая идея кстати. Вот только остаётся ещё один вопрос (точнее этот вопрос возник от того что мало опыта у меня скорее всего)  При выводе как сравнивать ? if (in_array($row['card_id'], $aNoPriem)) {
    echo "<Цвет шрифта красный>";
} ? правильно ?)

Comment: Да правильно. Обычно назначают класс, например для тега а. `echo 'class="red";'`. А уже в css определяешь конкретный цвет.